# .htaccess on SiteGround doesn't support redirects using encoded spaces in file names?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect, mod-alias

I'm here after not having success speaking with the tech support at SiteGround.com. I can redirect any file, using proper rules in the .htaccess file, EXCEPT for files that contain a space.  This despite the fact that I properly encode any space using %20.  Here is the code:

```
Redirect permanent "/pdf/Adam%20Teachings.pdf" "/pdf/Adam.pdf"
```

If I am in the /pdf directory on my website, and I click the link for "Adam Teachings.pdf", the web browser then loads "Adam Teachings.pdf" instead of "Adam.pdf".  Is this ultimately a problem with the way SiteGround.com has their servers configured?  Or am I missing something in this one line of code?  Although other posts on stackoverflow talk about spaces in a htaccess file, none of the posts seemed to be my exact situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: `RedirectMatch 301 "/pdf/Adam\sTeachings\.pdf$" "/pdf/Adam.pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Redirect permanent "/pdf/Adam%20Teachings.pdf" "/pdf/Adam.pdf"
> ```

The mod_alias (not mod_rewrite) `Redirect` directive matches against the %-decoded URL-path, so unless the *space* is erroneously doubly encoded in the initial request (ie. as `%2520`) then you should be matching against a literal space here, not `%20`.

In other words, it should be:

```
Redirect permanent "/pdf/Adam Teachings.pdf" "/pdf/Adam.pdf"
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect